# How to plot graphs iteratively on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I'm working with incremental graphs, so I would like to plot the current graph every time I insert a new edge on top of the previous drawing.

With this code I can generate one figure at a time, but they only show up after the iteration has ended.

```
import random
import time
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

#Generating some random edges
M = 10
N = 4
edges = []
for i in range(M):
    s = random.randrange(N) + 1
    t = random.randrange(N) + 1
    edges.append((s,t))

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(range(1, 5))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.ion()

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

for edge in edges:
    plt.figure()
    G.add_edge(*edge)
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
    time.sleep(1)
```

But what I really want is to see the graph being redrawn on every iteration, or at least being able to stack them using Matplotlib's interactive mode so I can go forward and backward.

I've been searching for days and have found some examples working with graphs like bar chart, pie chart and such, but the graph I mean is the data structure, not charts.

Comment: `plt.draw()` would update an interactive plot. `plt.pause(...)` would add a pause. `time.sleep(1)` will instead just block python for one second, which doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, but even with ´plt.pause´ the graph doesn't show during the paused time.

Comment: oh, I just saw that you create a new figure each second. That is surely not helpful.

Comment: Well, I can clear the screen using `IPython.display.clear_output()`, but nothing is drawn during the pause interval. Matplotlib's interactive mode apparently has the option to stack views in a single frame, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using `FuncAnimation`, which greatly simplifies the whole process of creating animated/live graphs in `matplotlib`

```
import random
import time
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

#Generating some random edges
M = 10
N = 4
edges = []
for i in range(M):
    s = random.randrange(N) + 1
    t = random.randrange(N) + 1
    edges.append((s,t))

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(range(1, 5))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(121)

def init():
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

def update(edge):
    G.add_edge(*edge)
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=edges, interval=1000., init_func=init, repeat=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for. I just added `plt.cla()` on the update method to clear the previous graph before drawing the next.

Comment: You're welcome. If you consider your problem solved, consider accepting the answer using the check mark on the left to close this topic